# javascript: bind() with first argument a function

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to javascript, and have run across what looks like an odd use of bind() I'm trying to understand. It involves the Razberry, a Raspberry Pi add-on to control a ZWave interface.

The ZWave interface is accessed via a webserver running on the Pi, written mostly in javascript. The software interface includes an event system which can be used for interprocess communication. The events are triggered by binding to various objects:

```
zway.devices[2].instances[1].SwitchBinary.data.level.bind(function() {
    state = 'on';
    if (this.value == '0')
        state = 'off';
    eventString = 'Device_2_Instance_1_' + state; 
    try {
        // do interprocess stuff via, e.g., sockets
        return;
    } catch(err) {
        debugPrint("Failed to execute script system call: " + err);
    }
});
```

The ...data.level object contains various properties, including 'value' as shown in the example code.

From my reading about bind(), I would've expected to see its first argument being something that would become the 'this' within 'level', even though 'level' is not a function.

It appears like using bind() this way is intended to give the bound anonymous function -- the 'this' argument -- access to the properties of 'level', and get executed every time 'level' gets assigned. At least, I presume that's the goal, since the point is to raise an event whenever something gets assigned to 'level'.

Is this a reasonable interpretation? Are folks familiar with this construct/pattern to raise events?

**bind() source code**

Good point about bind() not necessarily being the default javascript bind(). I dug into the server source code and found the following:

```
// Create a function bound to a given object (assigning `this`, and arguments,
// optionally). Delegates to **ECMAScript 5**'s native `Function.bind` if
// available.
_.bind = function(func, context) {
    if (nativeBind && func.bind === nativeBind) return nativeBind.apply(func, slice.call(arguments, 1));
    if (!_.isFunction(func)) throw new TypeError('Bind must be called on a function');
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return function bound() {
        return executeBound(func, bound, context, this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};
```

It looks like the developers intend to emulate the native bind() functionality. So I'm still curious about how bind() behaves in this instance.

Comment: `.bind()` would ***return*** a callback function; since you don't seem to be using the return value of `.bind` at all, I'd suspect it's not the same `.bind` as the standard `Function.prototype.bind`, but some custom function specific to ZWave.

Comment: If `level` is not a function, then I would conclude that `level.bind` is another, unrelated method named `bind`.

Comment: "even though 'level' is not a function", if level is not a function it won't have `bind()` method

Comment: @Ramanlfc `var level = {}; level.bind = function () { };` ... \*cough\*cough\*

Comment: @deceze you are adding a bind method , i am talking about `Function.prototype.bind`

Comment: @Ramanlfc My point exactly. You're saying something can't have a `.bind` method if it's not a function, which is plainly not true. Ergo, `level.bind != Function.prototype.bind`, but `level.bind` still exists perfectly fine.